# Why do I get duplicate HSTS headers? AWS ELB, nginx, Ruby on Rails

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails

I'm running a set of Rails servers on AWS with elastic load-balancing and nginx.  When I run a security test at SSL labs (http://ssllabs.com/ssltest), it reports back:

```
    Invalid: Server provided more than one HSTS header
```

Where's that coming from, and how do I configure it to only report one HSTS header?

Answer (score 2):

Rails adds a HSTS header when you set `config.force_ssl = true`.

Since the error is that it's being duplicated, you're probably setting nginx to set the same header. Choose for either rails or nginx to do it, not both.